# JVM terminates when launching eclipse with J2SE 6.0 on mac os x (need J2SE 6.0 for Oracle enterprise pack for eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, macos, java, jvm-crash

I know my issue has party been addressed at this link

[JVM terminates when launching Eclipse MAT on Mac OS with J2SE 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245803/jvm-terminates-when-launching-eclipse-mat-on-mac-os-with-j2se-60)

but it was a year+ ago.. plus the link that's provided in there 
http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/static/soylatte/

does not seem to be alive (i mean the download section on that link no longer provide the 32-bit port of j2se 6.0 for mac osx 10.5)

I am trying to run eclipse 3.5 on mac OSX 10.5. It works fine with J2SE 5.0. But when I installed the Oracle enterprise pack for eclipse - it requires to start eclipse with J2SE 6.0 JVM otherwise it will get disabled. Here's the exact message I get from it -

"You are running Eclipse on Java VM version: 1.5.0_22
Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse requires Java version 6 or higher. 
Click next to configure a compatible Java VM."

It asks me to point to J2SE 6.0 JVM, when I do that (i.e point it to "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home") , it asks to restart eclipse , when I do that, eclipse just bombs .. with JVM terminated error ..

SO I need to start eclipse with J2SE 6.0 JVM but eclipse needs carbon which is only available in 32 bits and hence I cann't start eclipse with J2SE 6.0 JVM which is only available in 64bit mode from mac. And the site providing 32 bit port of J2SE 6.0 JVM does not seem to be active anymore..

Can someone help me on this issue, 
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the cocoa 64 bit version from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/